# How to iptables REJECT outgoing traffic?

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking, squid

So I have a few docker containers running and each of them configured to use a certain network interface for outgoing traffic.

Let's say for an example that there is a docker network called docker_1 , using interface eth1 and I have marked its outgoing traffic with 0x0c3f (--set-mark 0x0c3f).

Now, if eth1 is down the container will default to use eth0 instead for outgoing traffic, this is unwanted behavior. I would like for the container to never use eth0 even if eth1 is unavailable.

I have tried running:

```
iptables -t filter -I OUTPUT -p tcp -o eth0 -m mark --mark 0x0c3f -j REJECT
```

It does not work.

Does anyone have any idea of what is not working properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to use the FORWARD - not output chain. Try changing "OUTPUT" to "FORWARD"